# JMP instruction - Hex code

Tags: assembly, hex, x86-64, machine-code

Have a doubt regarding the hex code conversion of JMP machine instruction. I have the absolute address I want to jump to, say "JMP 0x400835". 
First of all, is this allowed? If yes, what would be the corresponding hex code?
If not, can I first store the address in some register, say EAX and then put "JMP EAX"?
I am working on x86(64b) architecture.

I have tried to print out the hex code from the diassem output in gdb, but there is no consistency, ie, I do not see the destination address in the hex code.

I am new to hex code and machine instructions, so pardon my ignorance.

Comment: Related: [How to write an absolute target for a near direct relative call/jmp in MASM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50058523).  If the jump target is in range, some toolchains (e.g. NASM + `ld` on Linux) will assemble+link a jmp to an absolute address as a relative jmp from a known address (in position-dependent code).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There is no jump of the form `JMP absaddr` to an absolute address in 64 bit mode. The operand of a jump is always a 32 bit relative displacement to `rip`, which gets sign extended to 64 bit.

The reason you see no consistency is possibly that the offset depends on the the current instruction pointer and you didn't recognize that.

`jmp eax` isn't allowed either, as addresses are of course always 64 bit wide on a 64 bit architecture. A sequence `mov rax, addr + jmp rax` is possible, it would look like

```
48 c7 c0 35 08 40 00            mov rax, 0x00400835
ff e0                           jmp rax
```

or

```
48 b8 35 08 40 00 00 00 00 00   mov rax, 0x0000000000400835
ff e0                           jmp rax
```

How did I know these hex codes? Well, I did ask my compiler. I compiled with `gcc -c` and disassembled with `objdump`. I didn't bother to use Intel syntax, because I don't need it. So this is in AT&T syntax.

```
echo 'asm("mov $400835, %rax\n jmp *%rax\n");' > test.c
gcc -c test.c
objdump -d test.o
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This really helped me. objdump is seriously a good tool!

Comment: Hey.. I have marked your post as "useful".. that's what is needed I guess, right?

Comment: Do you mean "jmp absaddr" will be "jmp %rip + absaddr" (where absaddr has to be equal or less than 32bit)?

Comment: @ManofOneWay Nor sure what you are trying to ask, as there is no `jmp absaddr` and `jmp %rip+absaddr` isn't absolute. If you tell the assembler to translate some code in the kind of `jmp someaddr` it will calculate the relative distance from the current address (which will later on execution time be in `%rip`) to `someaddr` and emit `e9 xx xx xx xx`, where the four xx bytes correspond to the calculated address difference.

Comment: Here you write "jmp *%rax". Can you please tell where I can find description of this syntax? Because everywhere AT&T syntax is explained, this JMP syntax is not listed.

Comment: `mov eax, 0x00400835` / `mov $0x00400835, %eax` is only 5 bytes.  There's zero benefit to sign-extending that immediate with a 64-bit `mov` instead of relying on implicit zero-extension from writing EAX.   [Why do x86-64 instructions on 32-bit registers zero the upper part of the full 64-bit register?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11177137)

Comment: This comment is only 10 years old :) but I don't think "The operand of a jump is always a 32 bit relative displacement to rip" is not fully accurate. An example from this answer itself contradicts it: `jmp *rax` is an absolute (indirect) jump.

And thanks a lot for the "verify it yourself" sequence (`echo 'asm...', gcc, objdump`) -- very helpful (of course replacing `gcc` with `clang -x c`)!

Comment: @Vivek: Yes, indirect jumps exist.  More precisely, the operand of *direct* jumps/calls is always relative.  (64-bit mode doesn't have a version of `jmp far ptr16:64`, so we don't need to say "near" to be precise.)  So if the target address is encoded into the machine code itself, it's relative.    (Intel's [APX extensions](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/advanced-performance-extensions-apx.html) announced this week will add `jmpabs target64`, an absolute direct jump.  It'll be years before many people have CPUs with it, though.)

Answer (score 10):

If you don't want to use a register for whatever reason, it's also possible to encode a 64 bit absolute immediate jump as

```
ff 25 00 00 00 00           jmp qword ptr [rip]      jmp *(%rip)
yo ur ad dr re ss he re     some random assembly
```

rip refers to the instruction pointer AFTER the jmp instruction itself, so it's a pointer to your address.